# Program is printing memory values instead of actual values

Tags: python, printing, nslookup

Kind of got into a bit of a brain stump here. I was using the nslookup package and i wanted to get the ip address of a domain (in this case google). When I run the code below, i get an output of: "<nslookup.nslookup.DNSresponse object at 0x00000204C9001548>" instead of the ip address.

Code:

```
import nslookup

theLook = nslookup.Nslookup()

print(theLook.dns_lookup(domain="google.com"))
```

Yes, i know this is probably a stupid question but i swear, ive been searching for an answer and couldn't find one for my case. I also think i may have been able to solve this before but i can't remember how. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to print an object, which calls the internal `__repr__` of the Nslookup(). The response is in the .answer attribute, so :

```
print(theLook.dns_lookup(domain="google.com").answer)
```

should do what you need.

The documentation provides more details too:
https://pypi.org/project/nslookup/

> Returns an object containing two arrays:
>
> response_full: the full DNS response string(s)
>
> answer: the parsed DNS answer (list of IPs or SOA string)

Answer (score 0):

but you may also access the dict to get more details

```
import nslookup

theLook = nslookup.Nslookup()

for x in theLook.__dict__:
    for m in theLook.__dict__[x]:
         print(m)
```

and you will get output like this

```
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.102
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.101
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.139
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.138
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.100
google.com. 151 IN A 74.125.24.113
74.125.24.102
74.125.24.101
74.125.24.139
74.125.24.138
74.125.24.100
74.125.24.113
```